# Drawing contours on captcha image

Tags: python, opencv, captcha

I am trying to separate out digits in an image containing only digits. The digits are closely written and the contour builds on a random set of digits and I'm not able to separate it.

Original Image:

[image: 1]

Code I'm using:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image=image, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
```

The resultant image from this code is:

[image: 2]

I want to separate digits from this but due to contours building on a set of digits, I'm unable to separate them out.

Comment: did you try `cv2.erode`

Comment: The blobs are skewed, so they are joint together. You need some pre-processing steps before attempting to get their contours and their (I suppose) bounding rectangles. I don't think morphology will do here - you can try to erode the blobs but you will need a couple of iterations to separate the glyphs, and this will complicate the bounding rectangle approximation. Maybe try reducing the image to a row accumulating the sum of blue pixels on each column, and look for the areas of smaller accumulation to "partition" the blobs.

Comment: that's a captcha. it's designed to not be decodable that easily. joining individual glyphs defeats the simplest OCR (tesseract). you will need AI.

Answer (score 3):

In Austria there is a very nice verb, "pfuschen". Literally something like doing something just to the point that it works. I.e. take my answer with a grain of salt.

As mentioned by stateMachine in his comment, you can partition the digits by using the column-wise sum of the threshold. After that, you need to search for drops to identify the separations. Lastly, detect and shift the contour for each window.

Here's what I have so far:

```
im = cv2.imread("numbers.png") # read numbers
imRGB = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert to rgb for easy plotting
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to gray
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(imGray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # take inverse binary to have positive class as digits
columnWiseSum = np.sum(thresh > 0, axis=0) # sum each column
# the next two lines is to get the start of the first digit and the end of the last digit
firstNonZero = np.argmax(columnWiseSum != 0) # find last 0 in the first occurances of 0
lastNonZero = len(columnWiseSum) - np.argmax(columnWiseSum[::-1] != 0) - 1 # find first 0 in the last occurances of 0
peaks, _ = find_peaks(-columnWiseSum, height = -8) # get peaks, height was manually selected!!!!
peaks = np.insert(peaks, 0, firstNonZero) # insert start of first digit
peaks = np.append(peaks, lastNonZero) # insert end of last digit
# this is for plotting
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1, figsize=(4, 4))
ax[0].imshow(thresh)
ax[1].plot(-columnWiseSum)
ax[1].plot(peaks, -columnWiseSum[peaks], 'rx')
ax[1].set_xlim((0,120))
plt.tight_layout()
```

From the above code, I get the following results:

[image: Image and peak detection]

As you can notice, the maxima (because I negated the sum) occur at the split of the digits. Hence, you can define a window and a contour that can be drawn on the digits, BUT, first you have to shift it to its' original position:

```
contouredImage = imRGB.copy() # copy image for contouring
for i in range(len(peaks)-1): # loop through peaks
    startIndex = peaks[i] # get start of digit
    endIndex = peaks[i+1] # and end of digit
    window = thresh[:, startIndex:endIndex] # define window where the digit is
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(window, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # get contour from window
    X,Y = np.array(contours).T # unpack contour to X and Y coordinates
    X += peaks[i] # add the location of the peak, i.e, shift the contour to the digit location on the original image
    modifiedContour = np.dstack((X, Y)) # re-do contour
    contouredImage = cv2.drawContours(contouredImage, modifiedContour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1) # draw contour with red
```

From this I get the following results:

[image: Results]

Hope this helps you further, but I would expect that this solution is not universal and it will fail some, if not most of the time. If you have further pictures of the example you posted, include it in your post. I'll check later if the code can be applied in a better way.

Comment: @AlexKey I don't think that I can do it can be done with *all* the examples that you have in the link. Some numbers are really overlapping and hence the drop detection would not work. Though as my answer was pointing you in _some_ correct direction, I would appreciate if you close the question by accepting my answer, as your question was "detecting contours on numbers"

Comment: @AlexKey and now that you see how this problem is a bit too difficult to solve in this way, I think you should take Christoph Rackwitz's comment and think about CNN or DNN for captcha problems. Here is some resources for you: https://github.com/topics/captcha-dataset

Comment: @AlexKey given that captcha are made to avoid any fixed ratio or lengths, this would not be possible. As you can see from your examples, sometimes the same number has different sizes and orientations. Brute forcing is always an option, but again there is nothing as universal as you want it to be, only option you have imo is DNN or CNN.